# Calculate the electrical current density (international metric systeml )

Tags: power-electronics, current-measurement, amperage

I have a doubt about a result on a result. I have to calculate the electrical current density like $$\frac{\,\text{A}}{\,\text{m}^2}$$ I have the following parameters:

$$r=1\,\text{mm} =10^{-3}\,\text{m}$$
$$I=1\,\text{A}$$

so I have do this:
$$  j=\frac{I}{S}=\frac{1}{3.14\times (10^{-3}\times 10^{-3})} = \frac{1}{3.14\times (10^{-6})}=318471.3376\frac{\text{A}}{\text{m}^{2}} $$
Is this result correct?

Thank you

Comment: Seems fine to me. One amp on the numerator and 1mm squared pi on the denominator. Be careful that 1mm is the radius, wire is usually specified as diameter (or directly as sectional area)

Comment: Tips: in equations the units are not italicised. Also SI recommends a space between the numbers and units as in "5 cars" and not "5cars". so \$ 1mm \$ becomes `\$ 1 \ \text {mm} \$` = \$ 1 \ \text {mm} \$. Use `\times` = \$ \times \$ rather than *. `\cdot` = \$ \cdot \$ is another option. Finally units such as \$ \text {A/m}^2 \$ would normally be written that way or \$ \text {Am}^{-2} \$. +1 for the MathJAX.

Comment: It's probably correct (enough) but it certainly isn't accurately correct. Can you afford a calculator?

Comment: @Andyaka the problem isn't a calculator (I have a Casio FX-991ES, Wolfram Alpha and Symbolab). My question is to ask for a check of my method

Answer (score 2):

> Is this result correct?

Not entirely.

Things like current or radius are "physical quantities", i.e. they consist of a number multiplied with a unit. Any equation involving physical quantities are actually two equations: one of the numbers and one for the units. The product of  both equations needs to be correct at each step.

A simple example. You can write

$$ 1000 \mathrm{mA} = 1\mathrm{A}$$

That's perfectly correct since 1000 milliamps or 1 amp are the exact same physical quantity. However writing things like
$$I = 1$$, $$1000 = 1$$ or $$\mathrm{mA} = \mathrm{A}$$ are all wrong.

In your case, you should something like

$$J = \frac{I}{S} =  \frac{I}{\pi \cdot r^2} = \frac{1\mathrm{A}}{\pi\cdot 1^2 \cdot \mathrm{mm}^2} =  \frac{1\mathrm{A}}{\pi\cdot 10^{-6} \cdot \mathrm{m^2}}  \approx 318309.8 \frac{\mathrm{A}}{\mathrm{m^2}}$$

Every time you replace a physical quantity with a numerical value, you have to makes you use the correct unit as well.

In your last equation the first and the last terms are correct and they are current densities. However the middle terms are just numbers without units and that's wrong.

Comment: I think the usual standard is that variables are italicised and units are not. SI standard also recommends a space between the number (or variable) and the unit rather than your c-dot which is for multiplication.

Comment: @Hilmar perfect! Thank you for your explanation, this is really useful

Comment: @Transistor: good point. I tried to implement this, but the only way I could figure out was to use `\text{}` around each unit, which is super tedious. Is there a better way to this with Latex?

Comment: I use the siunitx package to properly format SI units in LaTeX, but I think that using \text{} is the only thing that works on this site. I also use a thin nonbreaking space `\,` between a quantity and its units.

Comment: Aside from all the lovely fancy formatting and unit consistency, I note that your numerical answer is in error (low) by a factor of 10:1 and OP's answer is only off by -0.05% (because of the 3-digit pi approximation).

Comment: @Hilmar, use `\mathrm` (math Roman) instead of `\text`. Text will render `\text {x^2}` as \$ \text {x^2} \$. `\mathrm {x^2}` will give \$ \mathrm {x^2} \$.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, thanks for the `\,` tip. I had never picked that up.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: Huh? I would think that using pi with high precision gives a more accurate answer than approximating it by 3.14. As far as I can see my numerical answer has a relative error of less than 3e-7

Comment: His answer is ~320,000 and yours is ~32,000.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Will fix it.

Comment: @Transistor thanks for the `\mathrm` tip. I learned something useful in answering a question :-)